# Use a parameter switch to change how a function behaves

Tags: function, powershell, variables, parameters

My main PowerShell code runs a function that logs to the Windows eventlog. If the level is error it uses a separate event ID which then our monitoring will pick up that exact ID and run an action. However, if I want to specify in the parameter of the main script (not the function) that this time running it use a different Event ID so it will NOT action monitoring, I don't know where to even start on that.

Is there a way to provide a switch parameter in the main script like `$NoAlert` which then changes the Event ID in the function?

The function of logging lives in a PowerShell module I created. I am importing the module at the beginning of the script and then calling the function during the main script body.

Here is the function:

```
function WriteLog-SRTProd {
    Param(
        [string]$logT,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)][string]$level,
        [String]$LogFileDirT = "\\ServerA\Logs"
    )

    $RSLogfileT = (Get-ChildItem -Path $LogFileDirT |
                  sort LastWriteTime |
                  select -Last 1).Name

    ## make sure a level is correctly selected (mandatory)
    if ("Error","Info","Warn" -NotContains $Level) {
        throw "$($Environment) is not a valid name! Please use 'Error', 'Warn', or 'Info'"
    }
    if ($Level -eq "Info") {
        Add-Content -Path "$LogFileDirT\$RSLogFileT" -Value "$(Get-Date -format MM-dd-yyyy::HH:mm:ss)  INFO   $logT"
        Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source TEST_MAINT -EntryType Information -EventId 100 -Message $logT -Category 0
    }
    if ($Level -eq "Warn") {
        Add-Content -Path "$LogFileDirT\$RSLogFileT" -Value "$(Get-Date -format MM-dd-yyyy::HH:mm:ss)  WARN   $logT"
        Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source TEST_MAINT -EntryType Warning -EventId 200 -Message $logT -Category 0
    }
    if ($Level -eq "Error") {
        Add-Content -Path "$LogFileDirT\$RSLogFileT" -Value "$(Get-Date -format MM-dd-yyyy::HH:mm:ss)  ERROR  $logT"
        Write-EventLog -LogName Application -Source TEST_MAINT -EntryType Error -EventId 300 -Message $logT -Category 0
    }
}
```

I'd like to run my script like this. When the `$NoAlert` is passed, it will send that switch to the function. Is this possible? Can I just add the switch in both places and use an `if` statement in the function for when the NoAlert switch is used?

```
PS C:\> .\Maintenance.ps1 -NoAlert
```

```
Param(
    [switch]$NoAlert
)

WriteLog-SRTProd -level Error -logT "Custom Error Message"
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly. Add a minimal code example for example.

Comment: you will need to modify the logging function to accept a switch parameter. there is NOTHING you can do outside the function to change the code that exists IN the function. [*grin*] well, you can rewrite it ... but that is what just said.

Comment: So you are saying add a $NoAlert Parameter in the function? but what I want to do is use a switch parameter in the main code to trigger a different action (through an if($NoAction){ Write-EventLog -EventID 111 }. Im hoping to add that to the function so that when I use the parameter switch it in the main script, all the Error events change to EventID 111 instead of 300. That way I don't need to modify all the places in my main code that use the function. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: You could create a wrapper for the module function with an additional parameter `$NoAlert`, and then call that function, but that's about it. PowerShell is not Ruby, so no live-patching of functions.

Answer (score 0):

I have created own function for logging and stored/installed as module, below is the part of my log module :

you can customize the write statements and add your code for event log. I have added `'NoAction'` enum member as per your requirements.

I have used one Enum to separate the log levels

```
Enum Severity
{   
    Error = 3
    Warning = 4    
    Informational = 6
    Debug = 7
    Verbose = 8
    NoAction = 0  # AS PER YOUR REQUIREMENTS
}


function Write-Log()
{
    [cmdletbinding()]
    param
    (
        [Parameter(Position=0,mandatory=$true)]
        [Severity] $LogLevel,
        [Parameter(Position=1,mandatory=$true)]
        [String] $Message
    )

    $TimeStamp = "$(Get-Date -format HH:mm:ss)" ;

    Switch($LogLevel)
    {
        ([Severity]::Error.ToString())
        {
            Write-Error "`t$TimeStamp : $Message`n" -ErrorAction Stop
            break;
        }    
        ([Severity]::Warning.ToString())
        {
            Write-Warning "`t$TimeStamp : $Message`n" -WarningAction Continue
            break;
        }    
        ([Severity]::Informational.ToString())
        {
            Write-Information "INROMATION:`t$TimeStamp : $Message`n" -InformationAction Continue 
            break;
        }    
        ([Severity]::Verbose.ToString())
        {
            Write-Verbose "`t$TimeStamp : $Message`n"
            break;
        }
        ([Severity]::NoAction.ToString())
        {
            Write-Verbose "`t$TimeStamp : $Message`n"
            break;
        }

    } # END OF SWITCH   

} # END OF FUNCTION
```

**Sample Call :**

```
Write-Log -LogLevel ([Severity]::Informational) -Message "test log message using info level"
```

**Output :**

```
INROMATION: 09:40:15 : test log message using info level
```

Comment: Thank you very much! this is awesome! I will certainly incorporate this method in another form. However, I don't want to change the main script, rather have a switch that can change the function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to just add a new parameter to both function and main script named $NoAlert. I have added an If($NoAlert){WriteLog-SRPProd -NoAlert} to the main script (messy, but its what I needed done). then in the Function, If($NoAlert){EventID 111}. so basically I am using the switch in the main script that then calls the NoAlert switch in the function. This is all done with a few added If/Else statements.

Hopefully that makes sense. Like I said its not the best answer, but I wanted to get it done and still provide an answer here in this post.